# Is there an efficient algorithm for sampling from the negative hypergeometric distribution?

Tags: sampling, computational-statistics, hypergeometric-distribution

I'm writing a small statistics library currently. One of the algorithms I'm implementing has two variants: one that samples the hypergeometric distribution and one that samples the negative hypergeometric distribution. I've implemented and optimized the HGD variant, using the [H2PEC](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=J782) algorithm for sampling. I'm wondering, though, if there is an equivalent fast sampling algorithm for the NHGD. Alternatively, is there a way to change H2PEC so that it efficiently samples the NHGD?